# Yahoo Pipes - Build an RSS-URL using specific parameters pulled from another RSS feed's content

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

The main [Data Type](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=data_types) used by [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs) is the [Item], which is RSS feed content. I want to take an RSS's content or sub-element, make it into [Text] (or a number might work), and then use it as an INPUT into a [Module] to build a RSS-URL with specific parameters.  I will then use the new RSS-URL to pull more content.

Could possibly use the [URL Builder Module] or some work-around.

The key here is using "dynamic" data from an RSS feed (not user input, or a static data), and getting that data into a *Data Type* that is compatible (and/or accessible) as an INPUT into a module.

It seems like a vital functionality, but I cannot figure it out. I have tried many, many work-around attempts, with no success.

**The Specific API and Methods** (if you are interested)

1. Using the **LastFM API**.
2. 1st Method: user.**getWeeklyChartList**. Then pick the "from" (start) and "to" (end) Unix timestamps from 1 year-ago-today.
3. 2nd Method: user.**getWeeklyAlbumChart** using those specific (and "dynamic") timestamps to pull my top albums for that week.

**tl;dr. Build an RSS-URL using specific parameters from another RSS feed's content.**

Comment: Have you tried calling one pipe from another pipe? It seems to me that could work. Please post the URL of the feed that will provide the dynamic inputs, and the URL of the other feed you want to get based on the input.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by calling another pipe. You mean connecting one to the next?  I'm going to pull data from this  http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getweeklychartlist&user=aabowman&api_key=95b29b4b1c0fbfb0a4978e008913f943 . and use the "from" and "to" dates to format the following URL: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getweeklyalbumchart&user=aabowman&api_key=95b29b4b1c0fbfb0a4978e008913f943 .   Thanks for your help.

Comment: How will you use the "from" and "to" dates in the second URL? For example if from=1108296002 and to=1108294444 then what will be the second URL in this case? Please also post the link to the LastFM API docs.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should have posted the URL with those extra parameters in it. It will look like: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getweeklyalbumchart&user=aabowman&api_key=95b29b4b1c0fbfb0a4978e008913f943&from=1321185600&to=1321790400   .  Here is the info on the 2nd URL:http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getWeeklyAlbumChart .  the Last.fm API documentation: http://www.last.fm/api/intro

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. I doubt it is the best way, but it works. The problem was the module I needed to use didn't have and input node. But the **Loop module** has an input node, so if I embed the URL builder into the Loop module I can then access sub-element content from the 1st feed to use as parameters to build the URL for  the 2nd feed! Thanks for your help.   Then I can just scrap all the extra stuff generated by the Loop, by using Truncate.

Comment: Glad you figured out. You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out. I doubt it is the best way, but it works. The problem was the module I needed to use didn't have and input node. But **the Loop module has an input node**, so if I embed the URL builder into the Loop module I can then access sub-element content from the 1st feed to use as parameters to build the URL for the 2nd feed! Then I can just scrap all the extra stuff generated by the Loop, by using Truncate.